# How to update a program using Windows 10's PackageManagement system?

Tags: windows-10, package-management

Looking at

```
PS C:\Users\yzT> Get-Command -Module PackageManagement

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Cmdlet          Find-Package                                       1.0.0.0    PackageManagement
Cmdlet          Get-Package                                        1.0.0.0    PackageManagement
Cmdlet          Get-PackageProvider                                1.0.0.0    PackageManagement
Cmdlet          Get-PackageSource                                  1.0.0.0    PackageManagement
Cmdlet          Install-Package                                    1.0.0.0    PackageManagement
Cmdlet          Register-PackageSource                             1.0.0.0    PackageManagement
Cmdlet          Save-Package                                       1.0.0.0    PackageManagement
Cmdlet          Set-PackageSource                                  1.0.0.0    PackageManagement
Cmdlet          Uninstall-Package                                  1.0.0.0    PackageManagement
Cmdlet          Unregister-PackageSource                           1.0.0.0    PackageManagement
```

I don't see any option for updating software. So I guess there is no such a option like `apt-get upgrade` for the packages installed this way, right?

I mean, using the built-in modules, not installing chocolatey.

Comment: I can only tell you how to do it with choco. :)

Comment: @ferventcoder well... you and everyone who can type "chocolatey.org"...

Comment: I'm not sure if the built-in modules offer this. Definitely a good question and a good feature to add if it doesn't exist